# Executable not recognized in PowerShell. Possible issue with accented characters in path?

Tags: powershell, encoding, windows-terminal

I am trying to customize my PowerShell prompt in Windows Terminal using `Oh My Posh`.

I am following the docs but can't understand what I am missing. As instructed by the `Oh My Posh` docs, after the installation, I am adding the following to `$PROFILE`:

```
oh-my-posh --init --shell pwsh --config ~\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json | Invoke-Expression
```

I get the following error:

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\Jos├⌐ Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin\oh-my-posh.exe' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ (@(&"C:\Users\Jos├⌐ Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin\oh- ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Jos├⌐ ...\oh-my-posh.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:158
+ ... sh --config="C:\Users\Jos[char]130]") -join "`n") | Invoke-Expression
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

If I navigate to the path, the executable is there. Seems to be a problem with the path. As you can see it has a special character (é) and a space.

How can I solve this? I have tried several things with encoding, inputting the characters as ASCII, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is the output of the `oh-my-posh` command?

Comment: It outputs the prompt correctly. [link](https://ibb.co/vLhYh6P)

Comment: What is the **text** that is output by oh-my-posh?

Comment: Did you see the link with the image? Does that not answer your question? Maybe I am not understanding correctly.

Comment: You're showing what the prompt is. I want to know what is the **text string** that is passed as input to `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: Ok. So I should just run `oh-my-posh --init --shell pwsh --config ~\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json`, right?

Comment: Probably. I don't have this software to experiment myself.

Comment: It returns `(@(&"C:\Users\José Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin\oh-my-posh.exe" --print-init --shell=pwsh --config="C:\Users\José Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json") -join "`n") | Invoke-Expression`

Comment: @Synergix Due to the way the markdown rendered, it looks like there may be a \` (backtick) mark (the PowerShell "escape" character) in the output that was lost when you pasted due to the in-line code formatting.  To avoid any markdown issues, I'd recommend just pasting the output as the sole text of the comment this time.  Usually in-line is the right thing to do -- It just looks like it may be causing a problem this time.

Comment: You are right @NotTheDr01ds. Here it goes.

Comment: (@(&"C:\Users\José Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin\oh-my-posh.exe" --print-init --shell=pwsh --config="~\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json") -join "`n") | Invoke-Expression

Comment: So with the caveat that I'm not an Oh My Posh user, in reading the [docs](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/windows), I do agree that it appears to be a `PATH` issue.  From within PowerShell, does `$env:Path` have that directory?  If not, did you reboot after installation as recommended by the doc? A complete restart of Windows Terminal *should* have the same effect in my opinion, but the author recommends a reboot?  If you did restart, then double-check your Windows PATH via *Start->Run->Edit Environment Variables*.  Does it appear in the PATH there correctly (User or System)?

Comment: Yes, I had checked that before. `~\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin` is in the Path. I did reboot multiple times in the meantime.

Comment: Also. I have done `Test-path "C:\Users\José Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json"` and I do get `True`.

Comment: Apologies - In retrospect it should have been obvious to me from the error that it's at least picking it up in the path for the first execution.  I think we're all looking for something other than "bug", but at the same time suspecting that the problem really is the "é", the space, or both, especially given the error. So I would recommend trying to isolate that by creating a new user without any special characters, try it there.  If it works, create a third user with an "é" again and try again. If you can "prove" that's the problem, open an issue on the oh-my-posh Github.

Comment: Try to write the path "C:\Users\José Aniceto\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json" directly instead of ~\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\paradox.omp.json and check if the issue persists.

Comment: I have tried that @ReddyLutonadio to no effect. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but is your settings. json file saved in UTF-8 encoding? And perhaps this helps: Enable the new UTF-8 option in Windows settings. Go to the language settings, click Administrative language settings, then Change system locale… and tick the Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support option.